# Batch Getting user name from Active Directory using SID?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, active-directory, wmic, sid

The following script makes a backup of the data of each user's windows profile as long as each user has a folder in the backup location :

> ```
> @echo off
>
> set Target=D:\backup
>
> for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%SystemDrive%\Users\*"') do if exist "%Target%\%%~nXI\" (
>
> ........
>
> )
>
> pause 
> exit
> ```

I need to change the logon name of one user. After changing it in the Active Directory, the user's profile folder (C:\Users) keeps the old name.

From what I understand : the SID is linked to AD account and changing username and other properties are without effect on user's windows profile.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the new name in batch from its SID ? If yes, how ?

Any help would help me so much.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do it in _winbatch_, but I routinely do this in PowerShell. Would a PowerShell solution be acceptable?

Comment: Type `set` and look at your options, eg userprofile.

Comment: Something like `wmic useraccount where (sid='S-1-<RestOfTheSID>' and domain='%userdomain%') get name` I think

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all usernames, you can use `%` as wilcard

***CommandLine :***

```cmd
wmic useraccount get Name,SID
```

---

```cmd
wmic useraccount where "sid like 'S-1-5-21%'" get name
```

And when you use it with a batch file, you should double it with `%%` to escape it !

***Batch File***

```bat
@echo off
wmic useraccount where "sid like 'S-1-5-21%%'" get name
pause
```

---

You can give a try with this batch file , just modify to your desired SID if you know it !

```bat
@echo off
Title Batch Getting user name from Active Directory using SID
Set "SID=S-1-5-21-1718693495-2001798431-3107361897-500"
Set "UserName="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic useraccount where sid="%%SID%%" get name"') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined UserName set "UserName=%%~nb"
)
echo UserName = "%UserName%"
pause
```